# Create google maps trip from a .NET win-app?

Tags: .net, winforms, google-maps

I have a win-application that needs to reproduce a trip for a trucker according to a list of addresses.

I was doubting if it's possible to open a browser and transmit the addresses to the google-maps website so it creates the journey for me?

If the answer is no, I would you suggest to do it, if I don't have any website, I want it to be from the win-application, no server code.

Any ideas in VB.NET or C# will be highly appreciated!

I found few links that could help me out with Google-Earth like:
http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=VEarthControl

But I prefer not to spend to much time on it as it's an extra feature, I think google-maps would work better for me as it's online and I don't have to reinvent the wheel, the question is if it's possible to transmit a pocket of data that includes the addresses to gmaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few out there you could use:

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/171162

http://googlemapscontrol.codeplex.com/

Comment: greatmaps.codeplex.com is basically what I am looking for. but I don't see a way where I can create routes via addresses, I can only create them with coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use one of the example projects, you'll probably want to look through the Maps API: http://maps.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=23878